# Getting Cassandra column timestamp using hector

Tags: cassandra, hector

I'm using [Hector](http://hector-client.github.io/hector/build/html/index.html) to read data from a Cassandra DB.
An example for a query:

```
ColumnQuery<String, String, String> cq = HFactory.createColumnQuery(KEYSPACE, stringSerializer, stringSerializer, stringSerializer);
cq.setColumnFamily(columnFamily).setKey("Some_Key").setName("Column_Name");
QueryResult<HColumn<String, String>> cqRes = cq.execute();
```

The answer I'm getting (the value of this column) looks like this:

[45404,2]

As far as I know A Column consists of a name, value and a timestamp (As mentioned [here](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DataModelv2) for example).
I'm not writing to this DB, I only read from it. Is it possible that the datastamps are not written at all? Anyways, is there a sprcific way to pool it (the timestamp) using Hector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the getClock() method of the column to get the timestamp.  Every column has a timestamp in Cassandra.  (For counters it's more complicated and they aren't exposed to the client.)

However, the timestamp is used for conflict resolution, to see which write wins.  It should not be treated like a date field.  If you want to date your records then add a separate date column.  You can then have control over resolution, time zone, etc. and it can refer to the whole row rather than an individual column.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I did already noticed that the HColumn class has a getClock() method, but how to I get an instance of this class? The returned object does not have this method.

Comment: `HColumn<String, String> col = cqRes.get();`

Comment: I will be back on my laptop on Sunday and give it a shot. Looking good :) thank you.

Comment: In addition, it woth mentioning that in when using hector you should divide the timestamp by 1000 (since hector is using public long createClock() {
    return getSystemMilliseconds() * ONE_THOUSAND;
  }
 when saving).